# audacity: silence audio have still plays some noise

Tags: audacity

I have a completely silence audio made from audacity. But when i convert it to wav 8bit/16bit and play it, it still plays some noise when the volume is max. So how to make a completely silence audio using audacity.

I have another audio where i have add few seconds of silence inbetween. I have converted that audio to wav 8bit/16bit. When i play the audio in full volume it still plays some noise.

Because i play the audio in android using audiotrack.write() it plays buzzing sound

Answer (score 0):

The noise might be generated by the electronic equipment you are using to play the track, not by the digital file itself. There is always a bit of noise and it cannot be avoided completely. You can reduce it by buying more sophisticated headphones/sound cards, woofers etc.

Take a look at the [Signal-To-Noise-Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio) concept. If there is no signal (silent track) at max volume it is easier to hear noise that otherwise is hidden by the signal.